# How can I create a program that requests the user for a grade between 0.0 and 1.0 and returns a specific letter if within threshold

Tags: exception, while-loop, conditional-statements, try-catch

```
try:
    nota= float(input("Introduzca nota entre 0.0 y 1.0 or pare ejecucion escribiendo Q o q"))
except:
    print("Respuesta no valida")
    continue
    
while True: #Validar si el rango esta entre 0.0 y 1.0
    if nota=="Q" or nota=="q":
        print("Bye")
        break
        if (nota>=0.0 and nota<=1.0):
            if  nota>=0.9:
                print('A')
            elif nota>=0.8:
                print('B')
            elif nota>=0.7:
                print('C')
            elif nota>=0.6:
                print('D')
        else:
            print('F')
            continue
    else:
        print("Respuesta no valida")
        continue
```

Multiple things with no luck. I cannot create the loop and break it